# Copy properties from one bean to another Bean implementing builder pattern

Tags: java, spring, copy, javabeans, builder

I have a `bean1`(With `Getter` and `Setter`) with hundreds of properties and another `bean2`(Implementing `Builder Pattern` i.e. using `Getters` and `Builder Pattern`).

I want to copy properties from `bean1` to `bean2`. How should I achieve that ?

Note:- `BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);` not working on Builder pattern bean.

Bean1 :-

```
package net.test.etest.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;


@XStreamAlias("POLICYDMO")
public class PolicyDTO implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5293821325394812329L;  
    @XStreamAlias("POLICYKEY")
    private long policyKey;


    @XStreamAlias("ADDRESSES")
    private List<AddressDTO> addresses;
    @XStreamAlias("POLICY_INFO")
    private PolicyInfoDTO policyInfo;
    @XStreamAlias("ELIGIBILITIES")
    private List<EligibilityDTO> eligibility;
    @XStreamAlias("POLICY_AGENCY")
    private PolicyAgencyDTO policyAgency;
    @XStreamAlias("PARTICIPANTS")
    private List<ParticipantDTO> participants;
    @XStreamAlias("VEHICLES")
    private List<VehicleDTO> vehicles;
    @XStreamAlias("PREFILLEDVEHICLES")
    private List<VehicleDTO> prefilledVehicles;
    @XStreamAlias("DRIVERS")
    private List<DriverDTO> drivers;
    @XStreamAlias("PRIOR_CARRIER")
    private PriorCarrierDTO priorCarrier;   
    @XStreamAlias("DISCOUNTS")
    private List<DiscountDTO> discounts;
    @XStreamAlias("COMPANIONPOLICY")
    private CompanionPolicyDTO companionPolicy;
    @XStreamAlias("PAYMENT")
    private PaymentDTO payment;

//  @XStreamAlias("BILLING")
    //private BillingDTO billing;

    @XStreamAlias("PAYMENT_PLAN")
    private PaymentPlanDTO paymentPlan;

    @XStreamAlias("POLICYTHIRDPARTYSTATUSES")
    private List<PolicyThirdPartyDTO> policyThirdParty; 

    @XStreamAlias("UW_RULE_RESULTS")
    private List<UWRuleResultDTO> uwRuleResults;

    private String violationsCallStatus;
    private String claimsCallStatus;


    public PriorCarrierDTO getPriorCarrier() {
        return priorCarrier;
    }
    public void setPriorCarrier(PriorCarrierDTO priorCarrier) {
        this.priorCarrier = priorCarrier;
    }
    public long getPolicyKey() {
        return policyKey;
    }   
    public List<AddressDTO> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }
    public PolicyInfoDTO getPolicyInfo() {
        return policyInfo;
    }
    public PaymentDTO getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }
    public void setPayment(PaymentDTO payment) {
        this.payment = payment;
    }
    public List<ParticipantDTO> getParticipants() {
        return participants;
    }
    public void setPolicyKey(long policyKey) {
        this.policyKey = policyKey;
    }   
    public void setAddresses(List<AddressDTO> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }
    public void setPolicyInfo(PolicyInfoDTO policyInfo) {
        this.policyInfo = policyInfo;
    }
    public void setParticipants(List<ParticipantDTO> participants) {
        this.participants = participants;
    }

    public List<VehicleDTO> getVehicles() {
        return vehicles;
    }
    public void setVehicles(List<VehicleDTO> vehicles) {
        this.vehicles = vehicles;
    }

    public List<DriverDTO> getDrivers() {
        return drivers;
    }
    public void setDrivers(List<DriverDTO> drivers) {
        this.drivers = drivers;
    }
    public List<DiscountDTO> getDiscounts() {
        return discounts;
    }
    public void setDiscounts(List<DiscountDTO> discounts) {
        this.discounts = discounts;
    }
    public CompanionPolicyDTO getCompanionPolicy() {
        return companionPolicy;
    }
    public void setCompanionPolicy(CompanionPolicyDTO companionPolicy) {
        this.companionPolicy = companionPolicy;
    }
    public PolicyAgencyDTO getPolicyAgency() {
        return policyAgency;
    }
    public void setPolicyAgency(PolicyAgencyDTO policyAgency) {
        this.policyAgency = policyAgency;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
    public List<EligibilityDTO> getEligibility() {
        return eligibility;
    }
    public void setEligibility(List<EligibilityDTO> eligibility) {
        this.eligibility = eligibility;
    }

    public String getEligibilityAnswerForQuestion(String question) {
        if(eligibility!=null) {
            for(EligibilityDTO e : eligibility) {
                if(e.getQuestion().equals(question)) {
                    return e.getAnswer();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public List<PolicyThirdPartyDTO> getPolicyThirdParty() {
        return policyThirdParty;
    }
    public void setPolicyThirdParty(List<PolicyThirdPartyDTO> policyThirdParty) {
        this.policyThirdParty = policyThirdParty;
    }
    public List<UWRuleResultDTO> getUwRuleResults() {
        return uwRuleResults;
    }
    public void setUwRuleResults(List<UWRuleResultDTO> uwRuleResults) {
        this.uwRuleResults = uwRuleResults;
    }
    public PaymentPlanDTO getPaymentPlan() {
        return paymentPlan;
    }
    public void setPaymentPlan(PaymentPlanDTO paymentPlan) {
        this.paymentPlan = paymentPlan;
    }

    /*public BillingDTO getBilling() {
        return billing;
    }
    public void setBilling(BillingDTO billing) {
        this.billing = billing;
    }*/

    public List<VehicleDTO> getPrefilledVehicles() {
        return prefilledVehicles;
    }
    public void setPrefilledVehicles(List<VehicleDTO> prefilledVehicles) {
        this.prefilledVehicles = prefilledVehicles;
    }
    public String getViolationsCallStatus() {
        return violationsCallStatus;
    }
    public void setViolationsCallStatus(String violationsCallStatus) {
        this.violationsCallStatus = violationsCallStatus;
    }
    public String getClaimsCallStatus() {
        return claimsCallStatus;
    }
    public void setClaimsCallStatus(String claimsCallStatus) {
        this.claimsCallStatus = claimsCallStatus;
    }


}
```

Bean2 :-

```
package net.test.etest.services.persistence;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import net.test.etest.services.util.IBuilder;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;


@JsonDeserialize(builder = PolicyDMO.Builder.class)
public class PolicyDMO {


    private final long policyKey;   
    private final List<AddressDMO> addresses;
    private final PolicyInfoDMO policyInfo;
    private final List<EligibilityDMO> eligibility;

    private final PolicyAgencyDMO policyAgency;
    private final List<ParticipantDMO> participants;
    private final List<DriverDMO> drivers;
    private final PriorCarrier priorCarrier;
    private final List<VehicleDMO> vehicles;
    private final List<VehicleDMO> prefilledVehicles;
    private final List<DiscountDMO> discounts;
    private final CompanionPolicyDMO companionPolicy;
    private final PaymentDMO payment;
    private final List<PolicyThirdPartyDMO> policyThirdParty;

    private final List<UWRuleResultDMO> uwRuleResults;

    private final String violationsCallStatus;
    private final String claimsCallStatus;
    private final String frOrderStatus;

    public String getViolationsCallStatus() {
        return violationsCallStatus;
    }

    public String getClaimsCallStatus() {
        return claimsCallStatus;
    }

    public long getPolicyKey() {
        return policyKey;
    }   

    public List<AddressDMO> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public PolicyInfoDMO getPolicyInfo() {
        return policyInfo;
    }

    public List<ParticipantDMO> getParticipants() {
        return participants;
    }

    public List<DriverDMO> getDrivers() {
        return drivers;
    }

    public List<VehicleDMO> getVehicles() {
        return vehicles;
    }

    public PriorCarrier getPriorCarrier() {
        return priorCarrier;
    }

    public List<DiscountDMO> getDiscounts() {
        return discounts;
    }

    public CompanionPolicyDMO getCompanionPolicy() {
        return companionPolicy;
    }

    public PaymentDMO getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }

    private PolicyDMO(Builder builder) {

            this.policyKey = builder.policyKey;
            this.addresses = (builder.addresses != null) ? builder.addresses : builder.addresses;
            this.policyInfo = builder.policyInfo;
            this.policyAgency = builder.policyAgency;
            this.participants = (builder.participants != null) ? builder.participants : builder.participants;
            this.drivers = (builder.drivers != null) ? builder.drivers : builder.drivers;
            this.vehicles = builder.vehicles;
            this.prefilledVehicles = builder.prefilledVehicles;
            this.priorCarrier = builder.priorCarrier;
            this.discounts = builder.discounts;
            this.companionPolicy = builder.companionPolicy;
            this.payment = builder.payment;
            this.eligibility = builder.eligibility;
            this.policyThirdParty = builder.policyThirdParty;
            this.uwRuleResults = builder.uwRuleResults;
            this.violationsCallStatus = builder.violationsCallStatus;
            this.claimsCallStatus = builder.claimsCallStatus;
            this.frOrderStatus = builder.frOrderStatus;
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class Builder implements IBuilder<PolicyDMO> {
        private long policyKey;
        /*
         * private String company; private String state; private String lob;
         * private String channel;
         */     
        private List<AddressDMO> addresses;
        private PolicyInfoDMO policyInfo;
        private PolicyAgencyDMO policyAgency;
        private List<ParticipantDMO> participants;
        private List<DriverDMO> drivers;
        private List<VehicleDMO> vehicles;
        private List<VehicleDMO> prefilledVehicles;
        private PriorCarrier priorCarrier;
        private List<DiscountDMO> discounts;
        private CompanionPolicyDMO companionPolicy;
        private PaymentDMO payment;
        private List<EligibilityDMO> eligibility;
        private List<PolicyThirdPartyDMO> policyThirdParty;
        private List<UWRuleResultDMO> uwRuleResults;
        private String violationsCallStatus;
        private String claimsCallStatus;
        private String frOrderStatus;

        public Builder withDrivers(List<DriverDMO> drivers) {
            this.drivers = drivers;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPriorCarrier(PriorCarrier priorCarrier) {
            this.priorCarrier = priorCarrier;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withVehicles(List<VehicleDMO> vehicles) {
            this.vehicles = vehicles;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPrefilledVehicles(List<VehicleDMO> prefilledVehicles) {
            this.prefilledVehicles = prefilledVehicles;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPolicyKey(long policyKey) {
            this.policyKey = policyKey;
            return this;
        }       

        public Builder withAddresses(List<AddressDMO> addresses) {
            this.addresses = addresses;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPolicyInfo(PolicyInfoDMO policyInfo) {
            this.policyInfo = policyInfo;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPolicyAgency(PolicyAgencyDMO policyAgency) {
            this.policyAgency = policyAgency;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withParticipants(List<ParticipantDMO> participants) {
            this.participants = participants;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withDiscounts(List<DiscountDMO> discounts) {
            this.discounts = discounts;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withCompanionPolicy(CompanionPolicyDMO companionPolicy) {
            this.companionPolicy = companionPolicy;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPayment(PaymentDMO payment) {
            this.payment = payment;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withViolationsCallStatus(String b) {
            this.violationsCallStatus = b;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withClaimsCallStatus(String b) {
            this.claimsCallStatus = b;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withUWRuleResults(List<UWRuleResultDMO> uwRuleResults) {
            this.uwRuleResults = uwRuleResults;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder(PolicyDMO policyDMO) {
            this.policyKey = policyDMO.policyKey;
            this.addresses = policyDMO.addresses;
            this.policyInfo = policyDMO.policyInfo;
            this.policyAgency = policyDMO.policyAgency;
            this.participants = policyDMO.participants;
            this.drivers = policyDMO.drivers;
            this.vehicles = policyDMO.vehicles;
            this.prefilledVehicles = policyDMO.prefilledVehicles;
            this.priorCarrier = policyDMO.priorCarrier;
            this.discounts = policyDMO.discounts;
            this.companionPolicy = policyDMO.companionPolicy;
            this.payment = policyDMO.payment;
            this.eligibility = policyDMO.eligibility;
            this.policyThirdParty = policyDMO.policyThirdParty;
            this.uwRuleResults = policyDMO.uwRuleResults;
            this.violationsCallStatus = policyDMO.violationsCallStatus;
            this.claimsCallStatus = policyDMO.violationsCallStatus;
            this.frOrderStatus = policyDMO.frOrderStatus;
        }

        /* For Json deserialization */
        public Builder() {

        }

        public Builder withEligibility(List<EligibilityDMO> eligibility) {
            this.eligibility = eligibility;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPolicyThirdParty(List<PolicyThirdPartyDMO> policyThirdParty) {
            this.policyThirdParty = policyThirdParty;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withUwRuleResults(List<UWRuleResultDMO> uwRuleResults) {
          this.uwRuleResults = uwRuleResults;
          return this;
        }

        public Builder withFrOrderStatus(String frOrderStatus) {
          this.frOrderStatus = frOrderStatus;
          return this;
        }

        public PolicyDMO build() {
            return new PolicyDMO(this);
        }

    }

    public PolicyAgencyDMO getPolicyAgency() {
        return policyAgency;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }

    public List<EligibilityDMO> getEligibility() {
        return eligibility;
    }

    public List<PolicyThirdPartyDMO> getPolicyThirdParty() {
        if (policyThirdParty == null) {
            return new ArrayList<PolicyThirdPartyDMO>();
        }
        return policyThirdParty;
    }

    public List<UWRuleResultDMO> getUwRuleResults() {
        return uwRuleResults;
    }

    public List<VehicleDMO> getPrefilledVehicles() {
        return prefilledVehicles;
    }

    public String getFrOrderStatus() {
        return frOrderStatus;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please put your code here for clarity...

Comment: @DolphinJava Added the code, not sure if that is really required to answer this question

Comment: BeanUtil.copyProperties uses getter and setter matches for copying.  Which does not match in your case. That is the reason it wont work.

Comment: Why are you using Builder pattern? Any specific goals?

Comment: @DolphinJava The bean with BuilderPattern is being used at lot of other places in the project because of the builder patter advantages and I can't change that. Thanks!

Comment: Since this is used at various places, they must be doing the same thing that you want to do some where. Try to see how its been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the workaround by converting the bean1 to JSON and than converting JSON back to Bean2. Here is the code for that.

```
public static PolicyDMO createPolicyDMO(PolicyDTO policydto){

    PolicyDMO policyDMO = null;
    if (policydto != null) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            policyDMO = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(policydto), PolicyDMO.class);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (JsonMappingException e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    } else {
        LOGGER.error("unable to parse the object that is NULL");
    }
    return policyDMO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be any apparent easier way to copy data from a simple POJO to builder pattern bean. BeanUtils.copyProperties works only if getter and setter method names are matching in the two beans, which is not the case for you.

Adding setter methods, in your builder pattern bean will make it work, however your bean will not be immutable. And it does not seems like a lot of sense.

You may have to do the copy, the hard way.

Comment: I agree on what you are saying. The builder pattern will not work for copying the properties in such case.